# Abrir PDF en el host cliente

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Tengo una aplicación web desarrollada con jsp y servlets. En la página jsp solicito un documento pdf, el cuál se busca en el servlet, que obviamente está en el servidor. El problema es que, para abrir, utilizo la clase `Desktop d`, y al utilizar el método 
`d.browse(new URI(file://240.10.10.36/Documentos/documento.pdf))` 
abre el documento en el servidor y no en la pc cliente. Lo que yo necesito es que en la host cliente que solicita ese documento, se abrá dicha pc. Como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Puedes hacer que el cliente lo descargue y asi el elige si lo abre o lo guarda

Comment: No entiendo, como haría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para transferir un archivo de un servlet java a un cliente, se debe de recuperar dicho archivo como InputStream y mandarlo en la respuesta que el servidor dará a la petición del cliente. En este caso, se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
try {
  // Consigue el InputStream del archivo. Hay múltiples maneras de hacerlo, utiliza la que mejor te convenga.
  InputStream is = ...;
  // Copia el inputStream en la respuesta que dará el cliente al servidor. "response" es de tipo HttpServletResponse.
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
  response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Error escribiendo en la respuesta del servidor.");
}
```

De esta manera, el cliente (en este caso, el navegador), descargará el archivo recuperado en el servidor, o sea, el PDF. Si en vez de que se descargue, quieres que se muestre en la página, deberás utilizar en el jsp el elemento HTML llamado iframe. Un posible ejemplo sería este:

```
<iframe src="url que apunta al servlet del archivo"></iframe>
```

De esta manera, el PDF se mostrará en el contenedor iframe en tu página.

Más información sobre el iframe: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar los PDF directamente en un JSP, yo logre hacerlo del siguiente modo haciendo uso de la clase [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html):

```
Connection cn = null;
cn = clsBD.getConexion();
File reportfile = new
File(application.getRealPath("path/nombre_reporte.jasper"));
Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String HistoriaClinica = 
 request.getParameter("txtHistoriaClinicaConsumoPaciente");
String FechaInicial = request.getParameter("txtFechaInicialConsumoPaciente");
String FechaFinal = request.getParameter("txtFechaFinalConsumoPaciente");

parameter.put("HistoriaClinica", new String(HistoriaClinica));
parameter.put("FechaInicial", new String(FechaInicial));
parameter.put("FechaFinal", new String(FechaFinal));

byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportfile.getPath(), parameter, cn);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Esto lo trabaje con Jasper Reports. En mi caso, el cliente consultaba, y en base a los parametros enviados generaba el PDF y lo visualizaba en el navegador.
Espero sea util :)
[#FisrtAnswer]